# Intuition behind calculating the prefix and suffix sums

Tags: java, algorithm, prefix-sum

I am solving a [LeetCode question](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-number-of-operations-to-move-all-balls-to-each-box/): Minimum Number of Operations to Move All Balls to Each Box.

> You have `n` boxes. You are given a binary string boxes of length `n`, where `boxes[i]` is '0' if the `i`th box is empty, and '1' if it contains one ball.  In one operation, you can move one ball from a box to an adjacent box. Return an array answer of size `n`, where `answer[i]` is the minimum number of operations needed to move all the balls to the `i`th box. For input `boxes = "001011"`, the output is: `[11,8,5,4,3,4]`.

Doing it in `O(n^2)` is trivial.  I could only solve it that way.  I am trying to understand [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-number-of-operations-to-move-all-balls-to-each-box/discuss/1075595/Java%3A-O(n)-left-sum-and-right-sum) `O(n)` solution, but having a hard time:

```java
class Solution {
    public int[] minOperations(String boxes) {
        int n = boxes.length();

        int[] left = new int[n];
        int[] right = new int[n];
        int[] ans = new int[n];

        int count = boxes.charAt(0) - '0';
        for(int i = 1 ; i < n ; i++){
            left[i] = left[i - 1] + count;
            count += boxes.charAt(i) - '0';
            // System.out.println("i: "+i+" left[i]: "+left[i]+" left[i-1] : "+left[i-1]+" count: " + count);
        }

        count = boxes.charAt(n - 1) - '0';
        for(int i = n - 2 ; i >=0 ; i--){
            right[i] = right[i + 1] + count;
            count += boxes.charAt(i) - '0';
            // System.out.println("i: "+i+" right[i]: "+right[i]+" right[i+1] : "+right[i+1]+" count: " + count);
        }
        
        for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {
            ans[i] = left[i] + right[i];
        }

        return ans;
    }
}
```

Could someone please elaborate the logic behind:

```java
left[i] = left[i - 1] + count;
count += boxes.charAt(i) - '0';
```

I understand we increment `count` whenever we encounter a ball, but how does `left[i] = left[i  - 1] + count;` help us count the number of operations needed so far to move all the balls on the left to `i` (and vice versa in case of `right`)?

Thank you!

Comment: The basic idea is that moving from index `i` to index `i+1` increases the number of operations for each ball to the left. So if there are `count` balls to the left, then the total number of operations increases by `count`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This comment](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-number-of-operations-to-move-all-balls-to-each-box/discuss/1075474/C++Java-O(n)-LTR-+-RTL/857324) from [@dunkypie](https://leetcode.com/dunkypie/) helped:

> "I finally build the intuition for the problem using DP. Here is goes. When we say calculating the number of operations for moving all the balls to the left of a box to that bax, say we are at the i th position(or box). This consists of two parts, first dp[i - 1] will give us the number of operations to move all the balls so far till (i - 1) th position and now we have all the balls till the (i - 1) th position in the (i - 1) th position(or box). Then the next part involves moving all those balls in (i - 1) th position to the i th position. Also note the cost of moving a single ball by 1 position is 1. So the recurrence relation becomes:
>
> dp[i] = dp[i - 1] + (1 * balls) where 1 here is the cost of moving a single ball."

Answer (score 2):

Think of `left[i]` as the cost to move all balls starting from 0 to ith index.

So,

```
left[i] = 
  left[i - 1]  (cost to move all 1's to (i - 1) the index) 
  + count      (this is the total number of 1's which will all need to be moved to the ith index so, its cost is count)
```